# How do I set default decoder to playbin2?

Tags: c++, gstreamer

I'm trying to receive video stream, which is now mjpeg stream. In order to make program independent of broadcast protocol and video stream format I'm using playbin2. It works, but it takes a lot of time for playbin to connect to stream. I guess the problem is decoder, because when I tested:

```
gst-launch-0.10 soupthhpsrc location=http://some_location timeout 5 ! jpegdec ! autoaudiosink
```

and it works just fine. Connection takes something like 1 second. 
So the question is : Is there any way to set jpegdec as default decoder for my playbin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it is impossible to specify mjpeg decoder as the default for playbin2. t sounds logical to me, as playbin2 should automatically detect the format of the stream with which works. In the case of an unknown format playbin2 must report an error ([see code examples](http://www.massapi.com/class/pl/PlayBin2.html)). I think you need to properly setup mjpeg stream so it could be correctly detected using playbin2.

However, to realize what you have in mind, you can use the following trick:

First, you should try to run general playbin2 pipeline what capable decoding and playback different kind of the streams. If it works, then nothing else to do. Otherwise, you need to run an alternative pipeline, which decodes only mjpeg.

How to make an alternative pipeline, which decodes only mjpeg? You can try to make it using playbin2 (not sure that will work). To do this, you must explicitly specify the caps (using [gst_pad_set_caps](http://developer.gnome.org/gstreamer/unstable/GstPad.html#gst-pad-set-caps)) as 'image/jpeg' within the signal handler [source-setup](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-base-plugins/html/gst-plugins-base-plugins-playbin2.html#GstPlayBin2-source-setup). Otherwise, it is necessary to select another pipeline, for example, that you have specified in the question.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how it's gonna work(especially c++ implementation). Is it means adding custom souse element to playbin? If it is so, than, as I understand, I won't be able to receive anything but mjpeg over http.

Comment: And just to make sure, my question is understood in a right way: I need to receive video broadcasted via any protocol and any stream format (meaning at least those, playbin can handle). And I need playbin to first check if jpegdec is appropriate decoder for the stream, and if it's not, then search for an appropriate one.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Alexander. You've saved a lot of time for me.

Comment: Glad to hear that the answer is helpful. To speed up the startup, look at the standard utility qt-faststart (from ffmpeg).